# If $G = AB, A\cap B = 1$, then $AN \cap BN \le N$ for $N \unlhd G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G = AB$ with $A \cap B = 1$, is this relation reserved by taking quotients? If $N \unlhd G$, then of course
$$
 G / N = AB / N = AN/N \cdot BN/N
$$
as by definition $abN = aN\cdot bN$, but is their intersection still trivial. Is $AN/N \cap BN/N \le 1_{G/N}$? As $AN/N \cap BN/N = (AN\cap BN)/N$ this is equivalent with
$$
 AN \cap BN \le N?
$$
If $x \in AN \cap BN$, then $x = an = bn'$, i.e. we have $a \in bN$. So that $a$ and $b$ must lie in the same coset of $N$. But this is all I got. So does this hold, or does there exists a counterexample?

Comment: As a general rule, I think before asking a question you should at least consider groups of small order to check whether there might be a very small counterexample. (I am afraid the downvote is from me!)

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I am lost in computation! Just tried all the non-commutative ones. Added an answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt But their complex product does not give $S_3$! I have written $G = AB$ as an assumption at the beginning (which is much more restrictive than $G = \langle A,B \rangle$).

Comment: Ah yes. Well a subgroup of order $6$ together with a cyclic subgroup of order $4$ in $S_4$, would work, taking $N$ to be the normal suybgroup of order $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Derek! Let $a^2 = 1, b^2 = 1$ and $ab = ba$, then $V = \langle a \rangle \cdot \langle b \rangle \cong C_2 \times C_2$ and $N = \langle ab \rangle = \{ 1, ab \}$. We have $$
 \langle a \rangle \cdot N = \{ 1, a, ab, b \} = V
$$
and similar $\langle b \rangle \cdot N = V$, so that their intersection does not contain $N$.